# Which position do retro aldol reactions occur in (comparing glucose and fructose)?

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry, aldol-reaction, structural-biology

Regarding glycolysis, my text states:

> What is the biochemical rationale for the isomerization of glucose 6-phosphate to fructose 6-phosphate and its subsequent phosphorylation to form fructose 1,6-bisphosphate? **Had the aldol cleavage taken place in the aldose glucose, a two-carbon and a four-carbon fragment would have resulted.** Two different metabolic pathways, one to process the two-carbon fragment and one for the four-carbon fragment, would have been required to extract energy.

I am trying to understand this and I found [this](https://www.mdpi.com/molecules/molecules-21-00937/article_deploy/html/images/molecules-21-00937-sch001.png) diagram. It seems that glucose undergoes a [4+2] retro aldol reactions but fructose undergoes [3+3]. Why is this? What determines which position a retro aldol decomposition occurs in? Is there any particular reason glucose could not undergo [3+3] decomposition?